# C# Condition statement doesn't return true

Tags: c#, return, conditional-statements

I have a condition that compares two integers, but it never returns true even tho both numbers will be equal.

```
foreach (TreeViewItem item in Categories.Items)
            {
                if (subCategory.Tag == item.Tag)
                {
                    item.Items.Add(subCategory);
                }
            }
```

both are properties of TreeviewItem

```
TreeViewItem catItem = new TreeViewItem();
catItem.Tag = (int)row["CategoryID"];
Categories.Items.Add(catItem);
```

And

```
TreeViewItem subCategory = new TreeViewItem();
subCategory.Tag = (int)row["CategoryID"];
```

Even tho both values will become equal, the condition will return false and won't reach `item.Items.Add(subCategory);`

does anyone know what i'm missing? 
both are of the same type (int)...
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using `Equals` instead:

```
if (object.Equals(subCategory.Tag, item.Tag)){
 //...
}
```

Comparing as you did will compare references, so they are of course won't be equal.

You can also cast each `Tag` to `int` and compare the casted results but using `Equals` is more convenient in this case.

Note that an object also has an `Equals` method, you can also use this but it's not safe if the object is `null`.

```
//subCategory.Tag should not be null
if (subCategory.Tag.Equals(item.Tag)){
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

TrieViewItem.Tag is of object type. When you assign primitives to object reference they get converted to their corresponding classes, in your case Integer.

When you compare reference types using == operator you (unless the operator is overloaded) compare object references. The == operator will return true only if you compare a reference to itself. As your integer values are wrapped in two different objects, == will never return true.

You can read more about [object equality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd183752.aspx) on MSDN.

The correct way to compare in your case is:

```
if (object.Equals(subCategory.Tag, item.Tag))
{
   ...
}
```